# NetBeans IDE 7.0 <Missing Java EE Server>

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

*I created my Java EE Project with GlassFish server and Java EE 6. It was working good when i was created the project, but i closed my netbeans(there wasn't any fault just closed the NetBeans) and started my NetBeans.*

> Then problem on the title has faced. And i re-installed my NetBeans
>   many times. So i can't solve it. PLEASE HELP ME! NETBEANS GEEKS!

Comment: Check Tools -> Servers - is it listed there? And if not, can you add it?

Comment: Yes, i am using it. But i have created too many Glassfish servers... They are exist in the Tools -> Servers but not appear in the Solve box.

Comment: Have you also tried to reinstall Netbeans completely, i.e. manually deleting the `.netbeans` and `.nbi` folders and also manually deleting the Glassfish folder before new installation? Or try removing all but one Glassfish servers in the above menue and then create a new project.

Comment: yes, i deleted all files completely.

Comment: Weird problem... I can't really think of what else you could do. Maybe you'll have more luck asking the question on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you solved this already but I had this same problem just now. All I did to fix it was select a new server from the list provided when you click on the 'resolve this issue' after right-clicking on your web project. I selected apache tomcat, not the bundled version but the one I installed onto my computer and setup myself. The project then accepted that as the proper server to use and ran just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project and it gives at the bottom an option to resolve Server references, so once you click there, it gives the option to add the server (tomcat or glassfish), that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following place in your project's directory:

```
/home/<path-to-your-project>/nbproject/private
```

or

```
c:\<path-to-your-project>\nbproject\private
```

and check if the paths to GlassFish are correct in the `private.properties` file for the following properties:

```
j2ee.server.domain=
j2ee.server.home=
j2ee.server.instance=
j2ee.server.middleware=
```